# Repeated observations on binnary regression. When it can be classified as dependent observations?

Tags: regression, logistic, predictive-models

In order to model the probability of an event $ e \in (0,1) $ as a function of some independent variables we may face the situation where a group of individuals in a given time has $ e= 0 $ and in another time, without changing any of the dependent variables, has $ e = 1 $. Alo we may have another group of individuals not changing its dependent variable unless the predictors change somehow.

If, while building the model, we repeat the information of every individual every time we have information on them would we face any kind of problem regarding dependent observations?